# How to count clicks for several JButtons with ActionListener in if/if else statements

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm making a project for a voting-system with GUI using java.swing. The voting system contains of 5 candidates and when you click the vote button next to their name it should increment and display the number of votes that the candidate has at the moment.
I dont know why my code is not registrating and counting the votes of each button, i have tried to work through it but i am stuck.

code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class VotingSystem implements ActionListener{
    
    private static JLabel label;
    private static JLabel candidate1;
    private static JLabel candidate2;
    private static JLabel candidate3;
    private static JLabel candidate4;
    private static JLabel candidate5;
    private static JButton button1;
    private static JButton button2;
    private static JButton button3;
    private static JButton button4;
    private static JButton button5;
    private static int counter1;
    private static int counter2;
    private static int counter3;
    private static int counter4;
    private static int counter5;


    
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            new VotingSystem();
        }
    
        //Creating the voting system method
        public VotingSystem() {
        
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
            frame.setSize(750, 600);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(panel);
        
            panel.setLayout(null);
        
            candidate1 = new JLabel("Samir");
            candidate1.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
            panel.add(candidate1);
            
            candidate2 = new JLabel("Christina");
            candidate2.setBounds(10, 60, 80, 25);
            panel.add(candidate2);
            
            candidate3 = new JLabel("Philip");
            candidate3.setBounds(10, 100, 80, 25);
            panel.add(candidate3);
            
            candidate4 = new JLabel("Gilgamesh");
            candidate4.setBounds(10, 140, 80, 25);
            panel.add(candidate4);
            
            candidate5 = new JLabel("Gonzales");
            candidate5.setBounds(10, 180, 80, 25);
            panel.add(candidate5);
        
            button1 = new JButton("Vote");
            button1.setBounds(100, 25, 60, 15);
            button1.addActionListener(new VotingSystem());
            panel.add(button1);
            
            button2 = new JButton("Vote");
            button2.setBounds(100, 65, 60, 15);
            button2.addActionListener(new VotingSystem());
            panel.add(button2);
            
            button3 = new JButton("Vote");
            button3.setBounds(100, 105, 60, 15);
            button3.addActionListener(new VotingSystem());
            panel.add(button3);
            
            button4 = new JButton("Vote");
            button4.setBounds(100, 145, 60, 15);
            button4.addActionListener(new VotingSystem());
            panel.add(button4);
            
            button5 = new JButton("Vote");
            button5.setBounds(100, 185, 60, 15);
            button5.addActionListener(new VotingSystem());
            panel.add(button5);
            
            
            label = new JLabel("Number of votes");
            panel.add(label);
            frame.setVisible(true);
                
        
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
            if (e.getSource() == button1) {
                
                label.setText("Number of votes: " + counter1++);
            }
            
            else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
    
                label.setText("Number of votes: " + counter2++);
            }
            
            else if (e.getSource() == button3) {
                
                label.setText("Number of votes: " + counter3++);
            }
            
            else if (e.getSource() == button4) {
        
                label.setText("Number of votes: " + counter4++);
            }
            
            else if (e.getSource() == button5) {
                
                label.setText("Number of votes: " + counter5++);
    
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to create a `Candidate` class, one instance for each candidate.  Create a `java.util.List` of `Candidate` instances.  Construct your GUI using `JLabel` and `JButton` arrays sized to be the same as your `List`.

Comment: You should create and test a VotingModel before you start working on a GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button1.addActionListener(new VotingSystem());
button2.addActionListener(new VotingSystem());
...
```

You create 5 instance of the VotingSystem class, which means you also have 5 frames.

`Don't keep creating instances of the VotingSystem class`.

This means you need to completely restructure your code. For example you should not:

1. be using static variable
2. be using a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for some basic examples to get you started.

That is download the demos to see how they work. Then modify the working code to use your basic logic from above.